# Black Widow's story after Endgame

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* we saw Black Widow sacrificed her life to get the soul stone, but we know for a fact that there's a Black Widow movie in development from Marvel and supposed to release in 2020 but in *Endgame* she dies.

We know the future of Black Widow now. How is Marvel planning to set the storyline for this character? Hulk also said that he tried to bring her back but he couldn't.

In alternate timelines and prospects of that character being reintroduced in universe with some other capacity possibly but I think the key was really the moment where her father's name was uttered and she said "I didn't know that was his name". That seems to be priming for us I guess.

Comment: You seem to be asking for discussion which is not suitable for our Question and Answer format. You might be better suited asking this question on Reddit or Quora

Comment: Regarding the Black Widow movie we know **nothing** about when it will be set, it could be set anytime in the last 20 years or earlier.

Comment: it's not a discussion there are links which are telling us something about that character.

Comment: You are **asking** for a discussion on something which hasn't happened and that's not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events of *Infinity War* happened in 2018.

*Endgame* shows the passage of 5 years from that point, to 2023, when a rat steps on the right switch and frees Scott Lang, allowing him to bring the concept to the Avengers.  So it is 2023 Black Widow who goes on the fateful quest.

If Marvel follows the usual tradition of setting a movie in the year of release, then we'll be dealing with 2020 Black Widow, who is in the middle of administrating what's left of the Avengers.  That might not be the most exciting story, so I have a feeling *Black Widow* may be set in the past, as *Guardians* and *Captain Marvel* were.

Comment: they also gave hint about her father. So maybe it start from her childhood.